# Make Git ignore line breaks

Tags: git

When I do

```
git checkout development
git status
```

Git displays some file as modified:

```
On branch development...
...
modified: somefolder/somefile.sh
```

When I try to switch to another branch

```
git checkout my-feature
```

I get:

```
Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
  somefolder/somefile.sh
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting.
```

When I do

```
git diff somefolder/somefile.sh
```

it shows entire file content with red color and green color. The red content and green content are equal, the only difference is probably line breaks.

I work on some project where I can't change the content of that file, but need to switch to my branch somehow.

Is it possible to make `git checkout my-feature` command work in this situation?

Comment: just restore the file before branch change. `git restore somefolder/somefile.sh`
But if you have an issue on line break you should consider to fix this first

Comment: It works on WSL (Ubuntu under Windows), but Windows version of Git does not have `restore` command.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky, `restore` is `git` command, so it is present on all systems.

Comment: `restore` was introduced in 2.25, your Windows version is probably outdated.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky restore is in git since 3 year now.

Comment: Fix end of line usage using `.gitattributes` file so that files are always checked out with the same eol char whatever the platform. (And update your windows git version!)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can't completely ignore line breaks, because that is actual file content. Instead, seems like git automatically converts LF ending to CRLF on checkout. So if this is the case, you need to change your settings - see this article, for example https://davemateer.com/2020/01/09/Line-endings-ignore-in-Git.

```
# View current settings
git config --global --edit

# Change to not perform any conversions
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Answer (score 1):

> the only difference is probably line breaks.

You can verify this with `git diff -bw somefolder/somefile.sh` which then should show no difference.

---

With regards to resolving the difference that git reports, in my oppinion the best<sup>1</sup> way to resolve this is to run

```bash
dos2unix somefolder/somefile.sh
git add somefolder/somefile.sh
```

That will update both the worktree file and index to have correct line ending and, and thus should resolve any discrepancies.

---

For inspecting current status/debugging eol problems you can run `git ls-files --eol somefolder/somefile.sh` which then will give details on eol used in repository vs worktree.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is not affected by any configuration and is supported by absolutely all versions of git.